# Integer Array to String Array

Tags: android, arrays, gridview

want to change integer array to string array for viewing images in gridview.Arrayadapter only supports string arrays for animation in android `

```
int[] resource={R.drawable.chinanight,R.drawable.huhu,R.drawable.jkjkj,R.drawable.kkk};
String aa=Arrays.toString(resource);
String[] ay=aa.split(aa);

GridView grid;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grid_view);

    grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);


    ArrayAdapter ar=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ay);
    grid.setAdapter(ar);

    Animation asd=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.right);
    grid.startAnimation(asd);
}`
```

Pls Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of an adapter is to link a set of data to a set of views (which are created by the AdapterView i.e. ListView) - you don't give it an array of views to use.Create an Arraylist to refrence your drawables.

```
    ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>> array = new ArrayList<Pair<String, Integer>>();
    array.add(Pair.create("Drawable1",R.drawable.chinanight));
 array.add(Pair.create("Drawable2", R.drawable.dfg));
 array.add(Pair.create("Drawable3", R.drawable.sf));
 array.add(Pair.create("Drawable4", R.drawable.sdf));


 ArrayAdapter ar=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
    grid.setAdapter(ar);
```

Inside GetView() of your adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup container) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflator.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_list_row, container, false);
        }
        Pair<String, Integer> item = getItem(position);
        title.setCompoundDrawables(item.second, 0, 0, 0);
        return convertView;
    }
 };
```

Comment: well title is the widget i am using..You can change it with your widget